# We often need to reinstall our Xamarin.Forms app in order to receive notifications from GCM

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.forms

We are developing a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS. It implements Google Cloud Messaging for remote/push notifications. When they work, it works great. Sometimes, however, they do not work. We've found uninstalling and redeploying from visual studio or an APK fixes the issue. This is obviously not acceptable for production.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: @Razoomnick, I believe this is mostly solved for us. We needed to make sure we are reregistering the device on launch. I think we could also detect updates with GCM, but I cannot recall at this time.